# Umlauts in regexp matching (via locale?)

Tags: python, regex, locale

I'm surprised that I'm not able to match a German umlaut in a regexp.  I tried several approaches, most involving setting locales, but up to now to no avail.

```
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'de_DE.UTF-8')
re.findall(r'\w+', 'abc def g\xfci jkl', re.L)
re.findall(r'\w+', 'abc def g\xc3\xbci jkl', re.L)
re.findall(r'\w+', 'abc def güi jkl', re.L)
re.findall(r'\w+', u'abc def güi jkl', re.L)
```

None of these versions matches the umlaut-u (ü) correctly with `\w+`.  Also removing the `re.L` flag or prefixing the pattern string with `u` (to make it unicode) did not help me.

Any ideas?  How is the flag `re.L` used correctly?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Have you tried to use the `re.UNICODE` flag, as described in the [doc](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html)?

```
>>> re.findall(r'\w+', 'abc def güi jkl', re.UNICODE)
['abc', 'def', 'g\xc3\xbci', 'jkl']
```

A quick search points to this [thread](http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/python/python/850772) that gives some explanation:

> re.LOCALE just passes the character to the underlying C library. It 
>   really only works on bytestrings which have 1 byte per character. UTF-8 
>   encodes codepoints outside the ASCII range to multiple bytes per 
>   codepoint, and the re module will treat each of those bytes as a 
>   separate character.

Comment: Nope, I didn't (mea culpa), I wasn't aware of the existence of that flag, and it solves my problem!  Thank you, I'll flag this as the accepted answer soon (unless a more elaborate answer will also explain why my trials just using the locale flag did not work as expected.

Comment: If you're using Python 2, use Unicode strings (u"..."). Making the script UTF-8 is a good idea. Forget about the `LOCALE` flag, think of it as being for legacy stuff only (when you have no other choice).

Comment: Yeah, I read that sentence before posting my question.  Nevertheless it is strange that the "underlying C library" is so hard to be nudged into accepting the umlaut as a word-character (`\w`).  But, however, this seems to push the question away from Python and towards the C library which really is not my concern, as far as I have the solution with the `re.U`.  Thanks for that!

Comment: I think this stinking re.LOCALE flag should be removed from the documentation and never mentioned. It is a fake, hypocrisy and a trap for the person coding in a hurry.

Answer (score 0):

In my case `\S` gave me better results than `\w`, plus saving the file as utf-8, plus using `re.UNICODE`

Comment: Maybe in your cases, but `\S` in general also matches things like punctuation and special characters (e. g. ♯ or → or similar).  Not what I needed in my case.