# Why doesn't my regex catch ü?

Tags: python, regex

I am sorting a list of Chinese pinyin words and sometimes the letter ü comes up in the pinyin. Before I realized this I used the regex `([a-zA-Z]+[1-5]?)` to identify each syllable (pinyin words are written as the romanised pronunciation and then a tone marker, like `nü3xing4` or `ba4ba5`). That worked as I intended.

But then I came across the case that the letter ü could be in there, which isn't handled by the a-zA-Z regex, so I extended it to `([a-züA-Z]+[1-5]?)`, but that doesn't seem to work for some reason.

Both the source file and the unit tests have the `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` at the top and the files I'm sorting contains lots of Chinese characters which all seem to be properly handled. So what am I missing here?

Comment: I believe the answer can be found here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12240260/umlauts-in-regexp-matching-via-locale

Comment: It doesn't seem to work, but maybe that's because I can't use the \w character class since the flag seems to apply to the classes only? I can't see right now how I'd go about rewriting the regex to use those classes, but I'm pretty tired too. Maybe with fresh eyes tomorrow.

Comment: Is this Python 2, or 3? If it's Python 2, are you using `unicode` strings, or plain `str` strings, for your pattern and search string? (If it's Python 2, and you're using `str` strings, that's most likely the problem: use Unicode raw-string literals for the patterns, and make sure to `.decode('utf-8')` the search strings. Even with `re.UNICODE`, using byte strings doesn't completely work.)

Comment: Also, is it possible that you're searching decomposed (NFD) strings with composed (NFC) patterns (or vice-versa)? If so, you can't do that; you will have to `unicodedata.normalize('NFC', s)` before you can search it with an NFC pattern. (If the strings are coming out of Cocoa, they're often NFD.)