# Django slug, `\w` doesn't detect korean + chinese

Tags: python, regex, django

I have a regex for url:

```
r'^/review_metas/(?P<review_meta_id>\d+)/(?P<slug>[-~\w]+)/(?P<review_thread_id>\d+)/$'
```

The following url does match

```
/review_metas/2108/발견/24986/
```

The following url does **not** match and I wonder why?

```
/review_metas/2108/발견展/24986/
```

**EDIT**

I actually have

`url(r'^review/',
         include('review.urls', namespace='review', app_name='review')),`

review.urls have

```
 url(
     r'^review_metas/(?P<review_meta_id>\d+)/(?P<slug>[-~\w]+)/(?P<review_thread_id>\d+)/$',
         views.review.review_meta,
         name='review_meta_thread'
     ),
```

To try out Wiktor's suggestion, I tried adding `(?u)` after the `^` in each of the above two.  But it results in errors.

I tried imaluengo's suggestion

`r'^/review_metas/(?P<review_meta_id>\d+)/(?P<slug>[^/]+)/(?P<review_thread_id>\d+)/$'`

but it doesn't work...

** EDIT **

Sorry for the false call,

It was due to the client side matching of url (javascript regex) which didn't work.

Django handles it quite fine both languages at the same time.

Comment: Try adding an inline `(?u)`: `r'(?u)^/review_metas/(?P<review_meta_id>\d+)/(?P<slug>[-~\w]+)/(?P<review_thread_id>\d+)/$'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html):

> ***\w***:
>       When the LOCALE and UNICODE flags are not specified, matches any alphanumeric character and the underscore; this is equivalent to the set [a-zA-Z0-9_]. With LOCALE, it will match the set [0-9_] plus whatever characters are defined as alphanumeric for the current locale. If UNICODE is set, this will match the characters [0-9_] plus whatever is classified as alphanumeric in the Unicode character properties database.

You just need to add the flag [`re.UNICODE`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12240286/764322) for it to work and convert the string to unicode (as `u'mystring'` or `unicode(string)`).

```
>>> re.findall(r'\w+', '/review_metas/2108/발견/24986/')
['review_metas', '2108', '24986']

>>> re.findall(r'\w+', u'/review_metas/2108/발견/24986/', re.UNICODE)
[u'review_metas', u'2108', u'\ubc1c\uacac', u'24986']
```

---

In your example:

```
>>> expr = r'^/review_metas/(?P<review_meta_id>\d+)/(?P<slug>[-~\w]+)/(?P<review_thread_id>\d+)/$'
>>> url = u'/review_metas/2108/발견/24986/'

>>> re.match(expr, url)
None

>>> f = re.match(expr, url, re.UNICODE)
>>> f
<_sre.SRE_Match at 0x7f2e08dd8620>
>>> f.group('slug')
u'\ubc1c\uacac'
```

Just by passing a proper `unicode` string and adding the `re.UNICODE` flag your parser works fine.

---

I don't know how does [Django handle the URLS](http://blog.wearefarm.com/2014/11/26/django-unicode-urls/) internally (never used Django before), but if there is no way you can provide the unicode flag to Django, you can replace your *slug* pattern `\w+` with `[^/]+`.

```
r'^/review_metas/(?P<review_meta_id>\d+)/(?P<slug>[^/]+)/(?P<review_thread_id>\d+)/$'
```

It read as `anything but '/'`.

Answer (score 1):

use
    re.findall(pattern, string, flags = re.U)
or just
    re.findall(pattern, string, re.U)

You'll deal with the same problem if you have to parse any language using non-canonical latin letters (i.e., Czech, Russian or Chinese).

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
r'^/review_metas/(?P<review_meta_id>\d+)/(?P<slug>.*)/(?P<review_thread_id>\d+)/$'
```